# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, finding specific input tags

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I've loaded a webpage into my UIWebView and the page contains a number of input tags. I want to identify the one that looks like:


     `<input name="j_username" type="text" tabindex="1"  />`

Do you know what I would write in stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean identify? `document.querySelector("input[name=j_username]")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use document.getElementsByName:

```
NSString* jsString = @"var myElement = document.getElementsByName(\"j_username\")[0];";
[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```